# Keep getting 'Unexpected identifier' when running tests

Tags: command, syntax-error

I am trying to copy a tutorial for a Wordle solving bot but its just not going well. whenever I try to run a test on the code it doesn't work at certain points, I'll either get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'. I'm doing this on UIlicious.

**Here's what I've got so far:**

```
I.goTo("https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/")
I.click("reject")
I.see("Guess the Wordle")
I.click('/html/body', 40, 80)

let guessWord = null
for(Let r=0 ; r<6 ; ++r) {
    guessWord = solver.suggestWord(gameState)
I.type(guessWord);
I.pressEnter()
I.wait(2)
}

let rowList = document.querySelector("game-app").shadowRoot. //
querySelector("game-theme-manager"). //
querySelector("#board").querySelectorAll("game-row");
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably referring to the article I wrote here : https://uilicious.com/blog/automate-wordle-via-uilicious/

This test script, is designed specifically to use uilicious.com, so you will need to edit and run it through the platform.

You can do so via the snippet here : https://snippet.uilicious.com/test/public/N5qZKraAaBsAgFuSN8wxCL

If you have syntax error there, do let me know with a snippet link - and I will try to help you respectively.

Also the snippet you provided so far, excludes the "solver" class which was initialised much further down.